# Given path's format not supported error when moving report from Report Builder to VS 2012 report project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I created some reports in Report Builder for SQL 2012, before I realized that managing multiple reports is substantially easier in VS 2012. I created a reporting project in VS2012 and added the existing reports by right-clicking on the **Reports** icon in the solution tree, selecting Add ==> Existing Item and then navigating to and selecting the reports. I also added or recreated the data sources and data sets as needed.

Most of my reports "migrated" with no problems, and I was able to deploy them to a new dashboard and get a more unified experience for the users. However, a couple of the reports give the following error when I try to preview them:

The given path's format is not supported

Some of these reports deploy successfully and run in the SharePoint site, others do not. But my ask at this point is, can someone give me any tips on where to look for the cause of these errors? The Error and Output windows in VS2012 don't give file, line, or column info, so I just have no idea where to look. I have searched for as many URL or path references as I can in the query results, action targets, etc., and removed them when I found them, but the problem persists. If someone has any thoughts, or can tell me some settings to turn on in VS that might give me more information, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you can post the path?